# Repeat the set of controls based on the dynamic count in wp7 c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

Am having three textboxes and one textblock control inside a grid in XAML. In for loop I have to repeat the controls based on the given count. Please suggest any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <Count; i++)
    {
        var textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.Name = "txtblock" + i.ToString();
        textBlock.Text = "Dynamic Textblock " + i.ToString();
        var textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Name = "txtbox" + i.ToString();
        textBox.Text = "Dynamic Textblock " + i.ToString();
        GridName.Children.Add(textBlock);
        GridName.Children.Add(textBox);
    }
```

You can add Properties as Your Requirements

Comment: yes. I did like this only but in this way we doing means we have to set row and columns for each control on looping. I want the fixed design in XAML that to be repeated like layout inflater in android.

Comment: for that refer this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/resources/676/how-to-create-a-grid-in-wpf-dynamically.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try having those controls within a `Data Template`?

So that it'll automatically list according to your data.

```
<DataTemplate>
<TextBox />
<TextBox />
<TextBox />
<TextBlock />
</DataTemplate>
```

Or else try this way if you're going to go with a loop.

```
for (int i =0; i <2; i++)
{
textbox[i]= new TextBox { Text = str[i] } ; 

ContentPanel.Children.Add(textbox[i]);
}
```